# How to decode and fmp4 + chunked live stream

Tags: c#, http, video-streaming, encoder, decoder

How to decode and fmp4 + chunked live stream i get through HTTP GET in C# picture box ? I get the stream but the stream never ends so i could not convert it into Bitmap and display in picture box.